# How to implement a Logical Erase in Symfony 3?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, soft-delete

I am implementing a logical erase for my Symfony 3 entities.
On my entities, I added a `$deleted` field, and I created some delete-controllers with this code:

```
$entity->setDeleted(true);
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Then, I modified also my queries to avoid select 'deleted' entities. And works great.

**The problem:**

I have some entities with Unique Constraint (for example, email field on user table), so when I delete an user, and then try to add the same user with the same email, symfony shows a validation form error due to 'duplicated email'.

I tried to control this on controller in the following way:

```
$user = new User();

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        //Check for deleted duplication:
        $duplicatedUser = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
            ->getDuplicatedAndDeletedUser($user);

        if($duplicatedUser != null){
            $em->remove($duplicatedUser);
            $em->flush();
        }


        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }
}
```

But this code doesn't avoid the form validation error. First time when I try to create, Stymfony shows an error, and then, if I resubmit the form, it works because of the duplicated entity was removed from db.

How can I solve this issue?

**Note**: I know this: http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/softdeleteable.html but, I have already developed all the logic described, so I prefer go in my way with this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the sollution.

As you can see here http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions `handleRequest()` method validate the form, so delete the entity after that don't solve the problem at all.

I do that to get form data:

```
 $userName = $request->request->get('user')['email'];
```

And then check if this `$userName` is already used. If so, I delete the user **before** handleRequest() call.

Hope this help others.

Answer (score 0):

Something strange in your code, I can see a user getting created but it doesn't get injected in the form so it can be used to store data in it and I also don't see the form anywhere, was it created in the controller or is it pure html, if so, you would need to fill in the user with the data from the form with `$formName->getData()` function or if you so wish, fill in only individual fields with the `$formName['fieldname']->getData()`. Try this code:

```
$user = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
{
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     //Check for deleted duplication:
     $duplicatedUser = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
            ->getDuplicatedAndDeletedUser($user);

     if($duplicatedUser != null){
         $em->remove($duplicatedUser);
         $em->flush();
     }
     $em->persist($user);
     $em->flush();         
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I only put the esential parts of the code where the problem occurs. Your code are wrong, since you try to check de duplication inside the isValid() if.